# Setting up Vagrant/Puppet on a mac

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant, puppet

I have found a lot of great resources to set up virtualbox, vagrant and puppet. However I have hit a snag and don't understand where to go from here. I am not a sys admin or super man developer.

I go to run vagrant up and it loads almost everything with the exception of getting this error.
I have search for an answer but to no avail.

```
Running Puppet with ubuntu-apache2-sqlite-php5.pp...
stdin: is not a tty

Error: Could not find class apache for www.envisioncomm.net on node www.envisioncomm.net
Error: Could not find class apache for www.envisioncomm.net on node www.envisioncomm.net
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

FACTER_fqdn='dev.pyrocms-pro.sqlite' FACTER_hostname='www' FACTER_docroot='/vagrant    /www/pyrocms-pro/' puppet apply --hiera_config /vagrant/hiera.yaml --modulepath '/etc/puppet/modules:/tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-0' --manifestdir /tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests --detailed-exitcodes /tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests/ubuntu-apache2-sqlite-php5.pp || [ $? -eq 2 ]

Stdout from the command:
Stderr from the command:

stdin: is not a tty
Error: Could not find class apache for www.envisioncomm.net on node www.envisioncomm.net
Error: Could not find class apache for www.envisioncomm.net on node www.envisioncomm.net
```

I have a feeling this might deal with the vhost but not sure. I am still figuring it out. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you list everything you did step by step and the fields that you entered into puphet?

Comment: Well, I followed these instructions up until Step 4.

Comment: Well, I followed these instructions up until Step 4. Then I went to here https://github.com/pyrocms/devops-vagrant  and here  https://github.com/pyrocms/devops-puppet 

I did this because the git clone wasn't working.
I placed these into the vagrant folder. I then did vagrant up and it stopped like above. I am thinking it could be vhost but can not find any good explanation to help.

Comment: This is where I found good instructions for setting up vagrant. http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/vagrant-what-why-and-how/ 
At step 4 - Provisioning, I went to the Puppet link above and read through a bunch of it. Then see above.
If you have any good sites to share that would be great.

Comment: Okay So I followed the intire instruction list here and can ssh into vagrant...http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/vagrant-what-why-and-how/